# Load JS files from locally, not CDN

Tags: performance, caching, shopify, cdn

I am developing a theme based on Dawn,
I have added 2 JS files:

```js
<script src="{{ 'swiper.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="{{ 'swiper-handle.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
```

Problem:
Only file `swiper.js` is load from locally and file `swiper-handle.js` is load from a Shopify CDN??? WHY?

I took a long time to clear the cache of file `swiper-handle.js` but still can't do it.

Check my image:
[image]

Is there a way to force loading of files added below locally?
How to be like this?

```js
<script src="/assets/swiper.js?v=XXX" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="/assets/swiper-handle.js?v=XXX" defer="defer"></script> // Not CDN ( For dev )
```

Thank!

Answer (score 1):

if you add "//" in front the browser will try to fetch the file using
http/https based protocol ( http/https) was used to access the site.

So the url is resolving to "http(s)://cdn.shopyfy.com/....."

You can use below to load the file from the local server than from CDN using the source attribute as "src="/assets/swiper-handle.js?v=XXX"

To make sure you are loading the latest file, you can update the v parameter to a new value each time you update the swiper-handle.js file. Updating the v parameter make sure that browser cached file is not used and the file is fetched from the server.